# Streaming UTF-8 literals into QTextStream

Tags: c++, string, qt, encoding, utf-8

I am doing the following in a C++ source file that is UTF-8 encoded (Qt 5.7, GCC):

```
QTextStream textStream(&file);
textStream.setCodec("UTF-8");
textStream << "Copyright ©" << endl;
```

The resulting file is UTF-8 encoded but the `©` characters is not encoded correctly.

This fails because `operator<<(const char *string)` expects a Latin-1 string literal. Since the source is UTF-8 this doesn't work.

I also know how to work around this:

```
QTextStream textStream(&file);
textStream.setCodec("UTF-8");
textStream << QString("Copyright ©") << endl;
```

This works because `QString(const char *str)` expects an UTF-8 string literal.

I need to output a LOT of literal strings this way. I can't wrap all of them into `QString()`.

My questions:

1) Why does `QString` assume UTF-8 but `QTextStream` doesn't? Does this make sense considering Qt sources need to be UTF-8?

2) Is there a way to solve this without hundreds of `QString()` wrappers (or similar)?

Comment: Seems this is a bug that will probably fixed in Qt 6 (see http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/commit?id=cec8cdba4d1b856e17c8743ba8803349d42dc701)

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in the [QStringLiteral](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#QStringLiteral) macro?

Comment: @MrEricSir: Yes, StringLiteral seems to work too. But the main problem (that every sinlge string needs to be wrapped) remains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) It does seem silly, especially if you take this quote from the documentation into consideration:

> Internally, QTextStream uses a Unicode based buffer, and QTextCodec is
>   used by QTextStream to automatically support different character sets.

2) You can inherit from `QTextStream` and provide your own `operator<<`. I'm not sure whether this is idiomatic Qt, but it works.

```
struct UnicodedStream : QTextStream
{
    using QTextStream::QTextStream;

    template<typename T>
    UnicodedStream& operator<<(T const& t)
    {
        return static_cast<UnicodedStream&>(static_cast<QTextStream&>(*this) << t);
    }

    UnicodedStream& operator<<(char const* ptr)
    {
        return static_cast<UnicodedStream&>(*this << QString(ptr));
    }
};
```

And if you don't care about using chained calls like `x << "foo" << "bar"`, you can use a more simplistic version:

```
struct UnicodedStream : QTextStream
{
    using QTextStream::QTextStream;
    using QTextStream::operator<<;

    QTextStream& operator<<(char const* ptr)
    {
        return *this << QString(ptr);
    }
};
```

Comment: Great answer, we ran into the same thing.  However, the simplistic version is very risky because (if I read it right) it will silently compile x << "foo" << "bar", but only "foo" will be treated properly.  I'd suggest that the second one return void to prevent that -- or, just use the first one.

Comment: Sorry for the second comment.  See also QTBUG-54942. at https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-54942.